# CONNECTION_REFUSED error, trying to connect Node and Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, connection-refused

localhost:3001/vehicle is giving me data from database.

I have this in my config() in app.ts

```
this.app.use((req,res,next) =>{
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,Accept,Authorization');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

            next();
        })
```

[image]
Tried deleting cache, flushing DNS cache, disabled extension on Chrome...

[Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9R67.png)

Comment: That's _not_ a CORS error, it's unable to connect to localhost:3001 to start with

Comment: Can you give me an advice how can I solve this? My backend says it is connected and the server is listening, and at localhost:3001/vehicle I am getting the data back from the database, but here I can not get them displayed in my table.

Comment: Show what is in your network tab?

Comment: Could you post an image of what you have in network tab @VidoJovanović ?

Comment: @MikeOne  https://ibb.co/xzbw2kg

Comment: @AntoineXevlabs https://ibb.co/xzbw2kg

Comment: Thanks. First of all, always disable cache :-). Secondly, as jon indicated, this does not look like a CORS issue (no OPTIONS request).

Comment: @MikeOne Gonna try something again I guess :( I am stuck two days on this

Comment: @VidoJovanović What's the output of your node console? Are there any errors logged?

Comment: @Andrei Can you be more specific, I am kinda new to all of this and a little bit confused.As I said, localhost:3001/vehicle is giving me the output in the browser, I can see the data from the database, the id of the vehicle, brand and model.

Comment: @VidoJovanović Did you start the server using `node index.js` command in a terminal or from VS Code?

Comment: @Andrei I started my server using the ts-node-dev server.ts command.

Comment: @VidoJovanović Ok so is there any output in that terminal where you ran `ts-node-dev server.ts`?

Comment: @Andrei https://ibb.co/mcLBps0 These two errors

Comment: @VidoJovanović These are from Angular dev server, we need the output from the Node.js server.

Comment: @Andrei In my dropdown menu in the output i have only Tasks, Extensions, VS IntelliCode, Microsoft Authentication, TypeScript, Angular, GIT, ThunderClient and JSON. :((((

Comment: @VidoJovanović That's the output of VS Code and it's not useful in this case, you should have a Terminal tab or a Debug Console tab, look there. If not look in the terminal window where you said you ran `ts-node-dev server.ts`.